# Turn python loop to jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I want to convert this code to jinja and I am having a hard time to convert it to jinja:

```
for item in iter(results):
    for i in iter(list(item)):
        if(type(item[i]) is dict):
            for k, v in item[i].items():
                print(k, ":", v)
        else: 
            print(i, ":" , item[i])
```

Can anyone help to change this code to jinja

Comment: instead of usingi `print()` save data in list and send this list to jinja and then use normal `for`-loop in jijna to display it.

Comment: Hi, 
Could you tell me how it could be saved in a list?

Comment: normally `my_list.append( [k, v] )` and `my_list.append( [i, item[i]] )`

Comment: BTW: if `results` and `item` is a list then you don't have to use `iter()`